# Fold-add all items in List, using Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, addition

I'm trying to write a function that recursively adds the first two items in a List, and returns when one item remains. 
Example:

```
addList([1,2,3,4], X) 
x = [10]
```

(Steps here would be: [1,2,3,4] -> [3,3,4] -> [6,4] -> [10] )

This is what I have:

```
addList([],[]).
addList([H|[H2|T]], []) :- L is H+H2, addList(T, [L|T]).
addList([H|T], [H2|_]) :- L is H+H2, addList(T, [L|T]).
```

In my mind, this would do something like the following:

```
addList([1,2,3,4], X).
L=1+2 --> addList([3,4], [3,3,4])
L=3+3 --> addList([4], [6, 4])
L=6+4 --> addList([], [10])
```

This actually causes an error - "Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated"

If I make the first addList into `addList([],[_]).`, it'll output `X = [] .` first, then have the same error if I use `;` to continue.
It should end in `false.`

(After having the chain of `X = [1,2,3,4] ; X = [3,3,4] ; X = [6,4] ; X = [10] ; false.`

Answer (score 1):

First, note that you can write `[H|[H2|T]]` equivalently as `[H,H2|T]`.

Also, as far as I know in Prolog the preferred style is to use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`.

```
add_list([H1,H2|T], []) :- ...
```

In the above clause, you already unifiy the second term with the empty list, and what happens in `...` is just a way of checking if the relationship holds. The `L` that occurs in the body is only a local variable; likewise, the recursive call to `add_list` is not used to compute the "result" (the second parameter).

You expect the result to always be a singleton list containing the total sum of your values, except if the list is empty (in which case the result is empty). The base cases are then:

```
add_list([], []).
add_list([N], [N]).
```

The general case is necessarily something like:

```
add_list([H1,H2|T], [Sum]) :- ...
```

And you have to expression the recursive relationship in terms of `H1`, `H2`, `T` and `Sum`. In fact until you reach a base case you are likely to only pass down the second argument unmodified, so you do not need to write `[Sum]` explicitly, you could just write `Res`:

```
add_list([H1,H2|T], Res) :-
    ...,
    add_list(..., Res).
```